# Yii framework: Using htaccess for site in sub directory not working on Hostgator

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

- I'm trying to set up Yii site to be loaded from sub directory to root domain. In my root site folder I have only root **.htaccess** file and sub directory "**subdir**" which contains Yii site. I found a solution that works on my local environment:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*) subdir/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
  ```

But when I upload the site to HostGator it just does not work correctly
For example

if I use `http://localhost/contact` on my local environment, correct page is opened (called site/contact - site controller and contact action. I've added Yii 'contact'=>'site/contact' rule to the urlManager, so both `http://localhost/contact` and `http://localhost/site/contact` can work)

If I use `http://mydomain.com/contact` or (`http://mydomain.com/site/contact`) on HostGator, I get default index page (called site/index - site controller and default index action instead)

When I choose to access subsites directly like `http://mydomain.com/subdir/contact` it works fine, but it does not work if I use `http://mydomain.com/contact`

I guess that I need somehow to change this last rule in htaccess, but not sure how. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found alternative solution that works. I was forced to use old fashioned URLs instead of paths, so I've changed my urlManager to:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                        //'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        'showScriptName'=>true,
                        'caseSensitive'=>false,
                        'rules'=>array(
                          ...
                         )
                    )
```

And my root htaccess looks now like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/index.php?r=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So, when accessing

```
http://mydomain.com/site/contact
```

Actual mapped URL is

```
http://mydomain.com/subdir/index.php?r=site/contact
```

which as result returns correct contact page

Answer (score 0):

Since, you stated in your previous question that `www.mysite.com/mysite/frontend/www/controller/action` works fine; you should be using:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53s .php .html

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mysite/frontend/www

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/frontend/www/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, previous question was not mine, it just helped me to fix the problem in my local environment, so I've added it as a reference, but will remove it now. I still have problem with this site on HostGator. Thanks!

Comment: @argonius, in your question did you mean that `mydomain.com/site/contact` works correctly or is it `mydomain.com/subdir/site/contact`? Can you shed some more light on your physical site structure please?

Comment: In my root site, I have only this root htaccess file and directory 'subdir' which contains my Yii site. When accessing my site directly I can use mydomain.com/subdir/site/contact or mydomain.com/subdir/contact (I've added urlManager rule for this contact=>site/contact so this will work too). I want to remove 'subdir' keyword from these URLs, but this does not seem to work on HostGator somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to edit .htaccess. You just need to move the Yii entry script (index.php) and the default .htaccess up from the subdirectory to the webroot (so that they reside directly under public_html). Once you move index.php and .htaccess to the root directory, all web requests will be routed directly to index.php under webroot (rather than to the subdirectory), thus eliminating the /subdirectory part of the url.

After you move the files, you will need to edit index.php to update the references to the yii.php file (under the Yii framework directory) as well as the Yii config file (main.php). Lastly, you will need to move the assets directory to directly the webroot, since by default, Yii expects the assets directory to be located in the same location as the entry script).

That should be all you need to do, but if you need more details, I describe the approach fully here:

http://muhammadatt.tumblr.com/post/83149364519/modifying-a-yii-application-to-run-from-a-subdirectory